# How to test for statistically significant differences between parameters for sigmoids fit to two different data sets?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance

I have two sets of data collected from two groups (group 1 in red, group 2 in blue). Each data set has been fit with a sigmoid with 4 parameters: Bottom Plateau, Top Plateau, Point of Inflection, and Slope at Point of Inflection. So for each group, I now have an estimate of the four parameters as well as confidence intervals (not depicted) for each parameter:
[image]

My questions is this: how do I test whether a specific parameter, for example the Point of Inflection, is significantly different between the two models?

One idea I had is to take the estimates for all the subjects in a group and doing an independent samples t-test for each of the four parameters. I'm not sure if a) this would be a valid way to test for statistically significant differences and b) is there a better way to do it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer PeterRabbit! Each parameter represents a component of a visual response behavior so I am more interested in whether each specific parameter in group A is significantly different than the same parameter in the comparison group, rather than whether the overall curves are different. You're right to assume the parameters are not independent so I'll look into Hotelling's T2 test.

Comment: I would just make sure all the assumptions inherent in the t-test are satisfied and keep in mind there could be more complex (and interesting!) issues involved.  For example, in group A, maybe the inflection point depends heavily on some other parameter (call it p1) while in group B the inflection point depends on p2.  If the parameter interdependencies are the same for both groups, go ahead and use the t-test I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a t-test for this, so long as you can consider the inflection point as independent of your other parameters.  If the parameters aren't independent (from your description I would guess this is more likely), you can also consider using a [Hotelling's $T^2$ test](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~ajw13/stat505/fa06/11_2sampHotel/01_2sampHotel.html) to test whether your first set of parameters is different from the second set.  The Hotelling's $T^2$ test is the multivariate generalization of the t-test.

The important thing to think about is what it means to be "significant".  How different do these parameters have to be for them to really physically be different in your situation?