# Statistical tests to compare sigmoidal regression equations

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

Data from my experiments (sample shown below) can be fitted using a sigmoid function. The equation I used to fit the data is: y = A2 + (A1-A2)/(1+(x/x0)^p).

Each experiment yields data (and a sigmoid fit) as show in the sample. I have performed a lot of such experiments and I want to test if the general characteristics of the dataset, i.e. the sigmoid fits, are similar (/significantly different).

I found a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89399/how-to-test-for-statistically-significant-differences-between-parameters-for-sig) in which the answer suggested using a t-test to compare coefficients of the sigmoid equation itself. Does comparing significance of coefficients equal to comparing the sigmoid as a whole? A small change in some of the coefficients might lead to a drastic change in the shape of the sigmoid whereas others might need drastic changes to give a small in the sigmoidal shape. So statistically different coefficients might not actually change the shape and statistically similar coefficients might change the sigmoid.

Is there a way to compare sigmoidal shapes as a whole and say these sigmoids are similar? Or should i just pick the feature of interest, like the slope of linear part of the sigmoid, and test for statistical significance between the slopes?

Thanks!

[image: Sample dataset from Experiments]